# Jenkins: How to publish artifacts to a git repository?

Tags: git, jenkins, publish, artifacts

I'd like to set up a Jenkins project that takes its input from one GIT repository, compiles stuff, and then stores / publishes the generated files to a [ideally different] GIT repository.

The "Git Publisher" post-build action doesn't seem to be able to do that, it only seems to be able to create tags/branches from the files I got from the repository. What I want to do is, I want to take the binaries that I created, add/modify them in a git repository, commit them, and push them. Ideally the results should end up in a different repository from the source code repository, but whatever is easiest, I'll take.

As far as I can see, my only option seems to be to write a custom script that does all the work using the git command line, i.e. git clone / copy / git add|stage / git commit / git push.

Any ideas?!

Comment: Just a stupid question :) Why not using Nexus or Artifactory to host your binaries? Git is more to host source code.

Comment: I want to keep my technology zoo at a minimum. I need traceability, versioning, and coordination between computers but can forgo file attributes, so git is entirely sufficient. We're a C++ shop, and I need to keep my coworkers in mind, so I can't just introduce all that Java-world stuff if the existing stuff can solve the problems at hand

Comment: That's like saying "I know that's not a nail but I still want to use my hammer." Buy a screwdriver!

Comment: That's like saying "I need a bread-baking machine in the kitchen for baking bread". I've been burned too often by having to use the tool/library of the day and then having to switch to something else a year or two later and lose all my data, so I try to pick good tools that I can use for a long time

Comment: OK thanks for your answer, I think the only option (as you said) is to write a custom script to push your binaires in Git.

Comment: Too bad. I was hoping that I could avoid that.

Comment: Short update: (1) Used the "Multiple SCM" Plugins to work with two repositories at the same time, (2) had to set some specific settings in order to be able to commit and push changes back, This kinda works, but I can't use changes in git as the build trigger as that leads to a continuous build cycle. Will post an update in a few days/weeks when I have sorted the problems out (and there is any interest)

Comment: Seven years later to now, I am interested in how you solve that issue. @CarstenKuckuk